# Microsoft access query populating a field with two different values based on condition s

Tags: ms-access

I have some issues writing a specific Access update query.

I need to compare data from `table_1` `field_1` and `table_2` `field_2`:

- if the data is present in both fields,
  `table_2` `field_3` should be populated with `Yes`;
- if data is present in `table_2`, but not in `table_1`,
  `table_2` `field_3` should be populated with `No`.

How to achieve that with code?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
UPDATE[Table2] INNER JOIN [Table 1] ON [Table2].[Field1]=[Table1].[Field1] 
SET [Table2].[Field3]="No";
```

I know this get me if fields are equal set as No . But I do not know how to write the rest of the command to say if table 2 field 1 isn't on table 1 field 1 set yes in field 3.

Comment: It most certainly is possible, but to help you we need Sample data and Expected result : [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: I have entered the code that I have

Comment: Updated question

Comment: There is no sample data.

Comment: You won't have a case of data appearing in `table_1` and not `table_2`?

Answer (score 1):

An `INNER JOIN` only return records where there's matching values in both tables.
A `RIGHT JOIN` will return all records from the table on the right of the join, and matching ones from the table on the left - NULL if the value doesn't exist.

This query will return FALSE if there's a value in both tables, or TRUE otherwise.  The TRUE/FALSE can be reversed by add the `NOT` keyword - `NOT Table1.Field_1 Is Null`

```
SELECT Table1.Field_1, Table2.Field_2, Table1.Field_1 Is Null
FROM Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field_1 = Table2.Field_2
```

Now, if `Field_3` is a boolean (Yes/No) field with the format set to `Yes/No` and the Lookup set to `Textbox` you can display Yes/No.

The query below converts the above SQL into an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field_1 = Table2.Field_2
SET    Field_3 = NOT Table1.Field_1 Is Null
```

Field_3 will now hold -1/0 which equates to TRUE/FALSE or YES/NO.

If, on the other hand, `Field_3` is just a text field you can use the `IIF` command to add the text:

```
UPDATE Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field_1 = Table2.Field_2
SET    Field_3 = IIF(Table1.Field_1 Is Null,'No','Yes')
```

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as correct answer if it is.

Comment: Would it be possible to write the same type of command if values are equal? Say I wanted to do the same type of command but if table 1.field 1 is equal to table 2 , field one how would I do that?

Comment: You'd change the SQL to `UPDATE Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field_1 = Table2.Field_1 SET Field_3 = IIF(Table1.Field_1=Table2.Field_1 ,'Yes','No')`